# Error : cannot encode a null Long

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to modify the bigquery-dataflow sample to work on CSV files. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-etl-dataflow-sample

I have changed the readObject to instead parse CSV and add that to datum object. While running the pipeline I am getting the following error:

> (2b01c6a9d56ae128): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CoderException: cannot encode a
>   null Long     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:160)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:288)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunnerBase.java:450)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:109)
>   Caused by: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CoderException: cannot
>   encode a null Long    at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.VarLongCoder.getEncodedElementByteSize(VarLongCoder.java:92)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.VarLongCoder.getEncodedElementByteSize(VarLongCoder.java:34)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.StandardCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(StandardCoder.java:185)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.KvCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(KvCoder.java:156)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.KvCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(KvCoder.java:42)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.WindowedValue$FullWindowedValueCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(WindowedValue.java:641)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.WindowedValue$FullWindowedValueCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(WindowedValue.java:552)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.MapTaskExecutorFactory$ElementByteSizeObservableCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(MapTaskExecutorFactory.java:351)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputObjectAndByteCounter.update(OutputObjectAndByteCounter.java:125)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowOutputCounter.update(DataflowOutputCounter.java:61)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:46)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:158)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:288)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunnerBase.java:450)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:109)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:139)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:188)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:55)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:221)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:182)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:69)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:285)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:221)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:171)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:192)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:172)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:159)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: please share your code

Comment: What kind of coder are you using? What type of elements are you outputting?

Answer (score 0):

The error is identical what I saw on [this question (mine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420458/using-cogroupbykey-with-custom-type-ends-up-in-a-coder-error).

You might want to double check if you're using KV but you accidentally assign NULL value to K. (It may easily happen if a CSV file has an empty value regarding a field you want to use as K)