# Using CoGroupByKey with custom type ends up in a Coder error

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I want to join two PCollection (from a different input respectively) and implement by following the step described here, "Joins with CoGroupByKey" section:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/group-by-key

In my case, I want to join GeoIP's "block" information and "location"  information. So I defined Block and Location as a custom class and then wrote like below:

```
final TupleTag<Block> t1 = new TupleTag<Block>();
final TupleTag<Location> t2 = new TupleTag<Location>();
PCollection<KV<Long, CoGbkResult>> coGbkResultColl = KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(t1, kvGeoNameIDBlock)
        .and(t2, kvGeoNameIDLocation).apply(CoGroupByKey.<Long>create());
```

A key has a Long type value. I thought it's done but when I run `mvn compile`, it outputs a following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project xxxx: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Unable to return a default Coder for Extract GeoNameID-Block KV/ParMultiDo(ExtractGeoNameIDBlock).out0 [PCollection]. Correct one of the following root causes:
[ERROR]   No Coder has been manually specified;  you may do so using .setCoder().
[ERROR]   Inferring a Coder from the CoderRegistry failed: Cannot provide coder for parameterized type org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV<java.lang.Long, com.xxx.platform.geoip2.Block>: Unable to provide a Coder for com.xxx.platform.geoip2.Block.
[ERROR]   Building a Coder using a registered CoderProvider failed.
[ERROR]   See suppressed exceptions for detailed failures.
[ERROR]   Using the default output Coder from the producing PTransform failed: Cannot provide coder for parameterized type org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV<java.lang.Long, com.xxx.platform.geoip2.Block>: Unable to provide a Coder for com.xxx.platform.geoip2.Block.
```

The exact DoFn which outputs an error is `ExtractGeoNameIDBlock`, which simply creates a key-value pair of its key (to be joined) and itself.

```
// ExtractGeoNameIDBlock creates KV collection while reading from block CSV
static class ExtractGeoNameIDBlock extends DoFn<String, KV<Long, Block>> {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
    String line = c.element();

    if (!line.startsWith("network,")) { // exclude headerline
      Block b = new Block();
      b.loadFromCsvLine(line);

      if (b.getGeonameId() != null) {
        c.output(KV.of(b.getGeonameId(), b));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`loadFromCsvLine` just parse CSV line, convert fields to each corresponding type and assign to its private fields.

So it looks I need to set some coder to my custom class to make it work.
I found a document referring the coder but still not sure how I can implement mine.
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/data-encoding

Is there any real example that I can follow to create a custom coder for my custom class?

[Update 13:02 09/26/2017]
I added

```
CoderRegistry cr = p.getCoderRegistry();
cr.registerCoderForClass(Block.class, AvroCoder.of(Block.class));
```

And then got an error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: in com.xxx.platform.geoip2.Block in long null of long in field representedCountryGeonameId of com.xxx.platform.geoip2.Block
```

[Update 14:05 09/26/2017]
I changed the implementation like this:

```
@DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
public class Block {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Block.class);

    @Nullable
    public String network;
    @Nullable
    public Long registeredCountryGeonameId;
:
:
```

(Set @Nullable to all properties)

But still got this error:

```
(22eeaf3dfb26f8cc): java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderException: cannot encode a null Long
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:191)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:436)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:424)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.join.CoGroupByKey$ConstructUnionTableFn.processElement(CoGroupByKey.java:185)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderException: cannot encode a null Long
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.VarLongCoder.encode(VarLongCoder.java:51)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.VarLongCoder.encode(VarLongCoder.java:35)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.encode(Coder.java:135)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.ShuffleSink$ShuffleSinkWriter.encodeToChunk(ShuffleSink.java:320)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.ShuffleSink$ShuffleSinkWriter.add(ShuffleSink.java:216)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.ShuffleSink$ShuffleSinkWriter.add(ShuffleSink.java:178)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.WriteOperation.process(WriteOperation.java:80)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.ReifyTimestampAndWindowsParDoFnFactory$ReifyTimestampAndWindowsParDoFn.processElement(ReifyTimestampAndWindowsParDoFnFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:183)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:436)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:424)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.join.CoGroupByKey$ConstructUnionTableFn.processElement(CoGroupByKey.java:185)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.join.CoGroupByKey$ConstructUnionTableFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:177)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:141)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:233)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:183)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:436)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:424)
    at com.bandainamcoent.platform.GeoIpPopulateTable$ExtractGeoNameIDBlock.processElement(GeoIpPopulateTable.java:79)
    at com.bandainamcoent.platform.GeoIpPopulateTable$ExtractGeoNameIDBlock$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:177)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:141)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:233)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:187)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:148)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:68)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:336)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:294)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:244)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:135)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:115)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share more of the pipeline? The error suggests the problem is in a ParDo called "ExtractGeoNameIDBlock" not the CoGroupByKey.

Comment: Thanks @BenChambers, I added the code. But I think anyway I need to add Coder to my custom class when I use custom class in DoFn because in some process of a pipeline, it may outputs data into file, so it needs to be encoded/decoded. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your custom class `Block` doesn't have a coder specified. You can create your own `Coder`, or use one of the general ones such as `AvroCoder`. You should also register it with the `CoderRegistry` so the pipeline knows how to encode `Block`s.

Comment: Thank you for the post! I updated my question. After I specify AvroCoder it outputs a NullPointerException for some field which may possibly be NULL.

Is there any way to tell AvroCoder explicitly that some fields are NULLable?

Comment: Ah..maybe this is relevent.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33443609/2543803
Let me try this first.

Comment: Hi, I could successfully run my pipeline using AvroCoder! Thank you so much for the help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it by using AvroCoder + Nullable annotations as I posted in update at 14:05 09/26/2017
in my question.

The last error I saw occurred just because my data actually has a null value which I didn't expect. After I handled null value in my Java code, everything works fine.

I think this post on another question is very useful for this problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32342403/2543803